# Enabling SSL for Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-7, ssl, group-policy, remote-desktop, rdp

Ok so I'm trying to remove a number of my systems from our Nessus scan from having this medium vulnerability.

[Microsoft Windows Remote Desktop Protocol Server Man-in-the-Middle Weakness](http://www.tenable.com/plugins/index.php?view=single&id=18405)

I set the following GPO setting:

Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Require Use of Specific Security Layer for Remote (RDP) Connections: SSL (TLS 1.0)

Once I do this my Windows 7 clients no longer have the Nessus problem however RDP no longer works from Linux or Windows clients.  I get the following errors:

From clients:

Linux:

```
[ryan@gobo ~]$ rdesktop -0 win7
Autoselected keyboard map en-us
ERROR: recv: Connection reset by peer
```

Windows:

```
"the connection cannot proceed becuase authentication is not enabled
```

One the server system (Windows 7 box running RDP):

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        TermDD
Date:          4/9/2012 4:28:58 PM
Event ID:      50
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      gobo-vm
Description:
The RDP protocol component X.224 detected an error in the
protocol stream and has disconnected the client.
```

and this one:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Schannel
Date:          4/9/2012 4:07:54 PM
Event ID:      36870
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      gobo-vm
Description:
A fatal error occurred when attempting to access the SSL server 
credential private key. The error code returned from the 
cryptographic module is 0x8009030d. The internal error state is 
10001.
```

I've seen solutions on this being a permission problem with the cert, as in the Network Service account doesn't have permission to access it but I can't find where the cert is on the filesystem to check it.

Other than that I'm out of ideas/options.  I look for the wise here.

Answer (score 1):

From [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff458357.aspx):

> A certificate is needed to authenticate an RD Session Host server when
>   SSL (TLS 1.0) is used to secure communication between a client and an
>   RD Session Host server during RDP connections. You can select a
>   certificate that you have already installed on the RD Session Host
>   server, or you can use the default self-signed certificate. You can
>   enable SSL for Remote Desktop connections using the RDP-Tcp Properties
>   dialog box, which is accessed from the Remote Desktop Session Host
>   Configuration snap-in.
>
> By default, Remote Desktop connections are encrypted at the highest
>   level of security available (128-bit). However, some older versions of
>   the Remote Desktop Connection client application do not support this
>   high level of encryption. If a high level of encryption is needed to
>   support legacy clients, the encryption level of the connection can be
>   configured to send and receive data at the highest encryption level
>   supported by the client.
>
> There are four levels of encryption available:
>
> **Low**
>  Data sent from the client to the server is encrypted
>   using 56-bit encryption. Data sent from the server to the client is
>   not encrypted.
>
> **Client Compatible**
> Encrypts client/server communication at
>   the maximum key strength supported by the client. Use this level when
>   the terminal server is running in an environment containing mixed or
>   legacy clients. This is the default encryption level.
>
> **High**
> Encrypts client/server communication using 128-bit
>   encryption. Use this level when the clients accessing the terminal
>   server also support 128-bit encryption. When encryption is set at this
>   level, clients that do not support this level of encryption will not
>   be able to connect.
>
> **FIPS Compliant**
> All client/server communication is
>   encrypted and decrypted with the Federal Information Processing
>   Standards (FIPS) encryption algorithms. FIPS 140-1 (1994) and its
>   successor, FIPS 140-2 (2001), describe U.S. government requirements
>   for encryption.
>
> The RDP-Tcp Properties dialog box, which is accessed from the Remote
>   Desktop Session Host Configuration snap-in, allows you to configure
>   the encryption level.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into your certificate setup. Have you purchased a third party SSL certificate? Or have you generated one from your RD server? Does it have a private key assigned, because it will need one.

It sounds like an issue with the certificate/private key. I would try add an 'import certificate to personal store' GPO rule inside of your RD host GPO and see if the RD host certificate is required for the client machines to connect. You have just forced SSL but have not installed/shown a trusted certificate.